# Welcome Intent displays responses other than what was defined in it

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I am creating an action in Google to save user's current location. In the Welcome-Intent I have defined two responses to user's greeting, which are

```
"Hey Hi! Do you want to save this location?"
"Would you like to save this location?"
```

Within this Intent I have several followup Intents which fire-up when the user accepts or denies the Welcome-Intent.

But in the first Intent, i.e. the Welcome-Intent, sometimes the responses from its followup Intents are displayed, however, it functions like the Welcome-Intent should function and accepts the phrases from the user like it should normally.

I am just not able to figure out how these responses from its followup Intents come up and display apart from the two which I have defined for it, I am not able to see any errors displayed anywhere.   I want to solve this problem and display only the two responses which I have defined for the Welcome-Intent. I am attaching the images for reference here- [Link 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBdXo.png) [Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrJJh.png) [Link 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz4zk.png)

**Edit**: Adding all the Intents with their context images
[All the intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMzMP.png),  [A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJ9f7.png),  [BY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6I14.png),  [CY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPJ1v.png),  [DY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsbit.png)
Initially they were in tree structure, but when I renamed all the Intents, the tree structure disappeared and they were visible separately, and the Intents were working but sometimes messed up the responses as I have described earlier.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will do it:

- You will need to add 2 follow-up intents to Welcome - YES & NO
- In welcome intent, just ask one question - "do you want to save location"
- In the YES follow-up intent, add an output context "save_location" and put the response "cool I am saving your location"
- In the NO follow-up intent, add an output context "dont_save_location" and put the response "Ok! I am not saving your location"
- Use the output contexts from YES & NO to make other Intents work in your app.

Your intent should look like this:
[image]

You can add follow-up intents by clicking "Add follow-up intent" and then selecting Yes or No 
 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly, I followed this method only to create the Intent Tree. And it exactly looks the same. However, it still mixes up the responses. I am not sure what the problem is, hope it's not a bug or something in DialogFlow.

Comment: Please update your question and show how the 3 intents look

Comment: See my updated answer. I think, from your All the intents image it looks you are not creating follow-up intents correctly. You need to click "add follow-up intent" at the right side of welcome intent as in my answer.

Comment: Exactly I did that to create them. At that time the intents appeared in the form of tree. But when I renamed them the tree thing disappeared. And even before renaming, when the intents were in tree structure, the same problem of mixing up responses was seen.

Comment: The tree structure will disappear if you change generated context names